# How to get Tableau server Admin password (Windows Instance) in AWS cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I need to include Tableau server Admin password (Windows Instance) during stack creation. But, I see steps for retrieving windows admin password is "Select instance --> connect --> provide pem key --> decrypt password." But how can I do this during stack creation in CloudFormation template? Please provide some guidance.

I tried below code under parameters for retrieving the password, but it's not working.

```
"TableauContentAdminPassword" : {
          "Description" : "The password for the initial Admin user for Tableau server",
          "Type" : "String",
          "MinLength" : "1",
          "NoEcho" : "true"
          "Default" : {"aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id  { "Ref" : "TableauServer" } --priv-launch-key { "Ref" : "KeyName" } }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tableau Content Admin Password is the password for the initial (admin) user in the Tableau Server itself, and you can choose any password you want for that. You'd use that username/password combo to login to the web interface after the server is installed.

The password you get via instance->connect->decrypt password, however, is the Windows password for the Windows Administrator account; you'd use that when RDPing to the instance. That username/password is unrelated to the Tableau Content Admin Password, and is chosen by Amazon when spinning up the EC2 instance.

Thanks to John Case who gave me this answer.